# SQLAlchemy Joining 2 tables using Junction table

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am learning SQL-Python using SQLAlchemy and will appreciate much help on this.

I have 3 tables,

Table 1 (Actors) : nconst (primary key), names

Table 2 (Movies) : tconst (primary key) , titles

Table 3 (Junction table) : nconst (from Actors table) , tconst(from Movies table)

I am trying to obtain 10 rows of actors that acted in particular movies. Hence I am trying to do an inner join of Actors on Junction table (using nconst) and then another inner join onto Movies table.

In SQL, this means

```
FROM principals INNER JOIN actors 
ON principals.nconst=actors.nconst INNER JOIN
movies ON principals.tconst=movies.tconst
```

In SQLAlchemy, my current code is:

```
mt = list(session.query(Movies, Principals, Actors).select_from(
join(Movies, Principals, Movies.tconst == Principals.tconst)
.join(Actors, Principals, Actors.nconst == Principals.nconst 
).with_entities(
Movies.title,  # Select clause
))
```

Alternatively, I am trying

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import join
mv = list(session.query(Actors).select_from(
join(Movies, Principals, Actors, Movies.tconst == Principals.tconst, 
Actors.nconst == Principals.nconst)  # Join clause
).with_entities(
Actors.name,  # Select clause
Movies.title,
))
mv
```

The error I am getting is an Attribute Error, "Actor type object 'Actors' has no attribute '_from_objects'

Appreciate much help on this. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the definition of `Movies`, `Principals`, and `Actors`?